# RegEx: Must have at least one number and letter but no other characters / whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

Got a bit stuck (RegEx isn't my strong point at all!) - I need an expression that will validate against any string containing only numbers and letters but must have at least one of each (upper and lowercase are interchangeable and allowed). It cannot contain special characters or whitespace.

Doing some prior research I have found this but it doesn't exclude whitespace and despite my attempts to do so I cannot modify it to exclude whitespace and special characters:

```
^.*(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

Some examples of strings that need to validate:

- ieoEon43
- 43ifsiojfdfs
- 6i
- ijf943kNFSfsf

Any help would be much appreciated! If it matters I am running these expressions in JavaScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)[a-z\d]+$/i
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kW3uR3/6)

Explanation:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VksK68S7D_2at4G6)

**Edit**: Fixed special characters issue.

Comment: Thanks - that's helped with the white space - but it seems to still accept special characters ( ie: fdfjf4343FFsk3£3%3£"&*(*&*) passes )

Comment: Sorry; missed the special characters point on the first pass. It works now.

Comment: +1, although the capturing parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Technically true, although I find most regex questions on SO want both validation and capturing even when the question doesn't explicitly ask for it, so I add them by default most of the time.

Comment: The group encloses the entire match, which is always captured anyway (in the implicit "group 0").

Comment: @TimPietzcker True. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Another attempt for fun and glory! (it's shorter!)

```
^([a-z]+\d+|\d+[a-z]+)\w*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JOhJaM2IoTV-jvwM)

**EDIT3:**

Made a small fix and it's now *DOUBLE* the speed of the other answer!!!

[**JSPERF**](http://jsperf.com/awdwadwadawd)

Comment: Nice idea, but it may fail on strings that start and end with the same class of characters (`1a1` or `a1a`).

Comment: @TimPietzcker fixed, I hope!

Comment: Much better (although `\w` also matches `_`) :)

Answer (score -4):

Iv done a demo on regxr 1.0 based on what I understood from your question.

If you follow this link you can see the demo yourself:
[Regexr demo](http://regexr.com/v1?38nmv)

UPDATED:
The regex is :
`/^([a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+)$/`

You can make it case in sensitive:
`/^([a-z]+[0-9]+|[0-9]+[a-z]+)$/i`

Comment: This validates `a`, which does not contain a number.